# Capitalizing titles

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a method that will capitalize titles. It should capitalize not every word, but only the big words if you will. Sometimes, it has to capitalize every word. Maybe I need to add an exception for the little words. It's part of a Ruby tutorial, and I can't use the Rails `titleize` method. Here is what I have so far. Please let me know if you can help.

```
def titleize(name)
  name.split(" ").each {|word| word.capitalize!}.join (" ")
end
```

Comment: You're doing a tutorial, and can't use `titleize`, but it's OK to have us help you? The idea of doing a tutorial is that you do the work and figure it out.

Comment: could u elaborate your question with some sample inputs and outputs you expect

Comment: I know I should be working through it on my own, but I'm running out of ideas. An example of an output would be "war and peace" becomes "War and Peace" or "the mysterious adventures of dr. cool" becomes The Mysterious Adventures of Dr. Cool". I'm working on constructing an if/else statement using the .include? method to check for small words in the string, but I'm having a little trouble with the syntax. Any advice?

Comment: You could also just exclude certain words such as: a, an, the, and, but, or, for, nor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off of Josh Voigts comment:

```
def titleize(name)
  lowercase_words = %w{a an the and but or for nor of}
  name.split.each_with_index.map{|x, index| lowercase_words.include?(x) && index > 0 ? x : x.capitalize }.join(" ")
end
```

You might want make lowercase_words a constant and move it out of the function since they won't ever change.

Comment: Thanks for the help johnnycakes. I tried what you were suggesting and it works for some of the tests if I replace the .titleize method in the block with .capitalize. It still doesn't seem to what to exclude those lowercase_words from getting capitalized though. Any more pointers? Or am I in too far over my head with this one?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixed.  I should have tested better.  First, yeah, I needed to use `capitalize` instead of `titleize`.  Second, my list of lower_case words had to be separated by spaces (instead of commas).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complicated problem, and @johnnycakes answer is a great start, but the list of lowercase_words is not exhaustive. Any preposition of 4 or fewer letters should not be capitalized, such as over, into, on, as, etc. Also, the last word of the title should always be capitalized in addition to the first word.

Wikipedia has a [list of English prepositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions). However, this is further complicated by the fact that some words can be both prepositions and verbs, so "I Like You" would capitalize "like" whereas "In like Flynn" would not.

The Rails titleize method seems to capitalize every word, whereas the [titleize gem](https://github.com/granth/titleize) does a slightly better job of following the actual style guidelines, though still without tackling the preposition problem.