# ruby regex scan vs .split method

Tags: ruby, regex

I was trying to build a method that you take the first letter of every word and would capitalize it. I wrote it as

```
def titleize(name)
   name.scan(/\w+/) { |x| x.capitalize! }
end
```

and it just wouldn't work properly. It wouldn't capitalize and letters. I did some searching and found the answer here [Capitalizing titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251311/capitalizing-titles) eventually. It was written as

```
def titleize(name)
   name.split(" ").each { |x| x.capitalize! }.join(" ")
end
```

How come my code didn't capitalize at all though? If I added a put statement and wrote it as

```
def titleize(name)
   name.scan(/\w+/) { |x| puts x.capitalize! }
end
```

It would output "hi there" with capitals but the => would still be just "hi there" What did I miss?

Comment: what was your code output? what input you have taken? how did you call your method?

Comment: @squiguy `#upcase` is not the  same as `capitalize`

Comment: I would enter "jaws" and it would return to me 1) 

Simon says titleize capitalizes a word
     Failure/Error: titleize("jaws").should == "Jaws"
       expected: "Jaws"
            got: "jaws" (using ==)

it runs through a rspec rake. its a tutorial i am working through.

Comment: There is no reason to call `capitalize!` if all your doing is printing it.  Just use the non-destructive version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
def titleize(name)
   name.scan(/\w+/).each { |x| x.capitalize! }.join(' ')
end

p titleize("ayan roy") #=>"Ayan Roy"
```

Let's see why your one not worked:

```
def titleize(name)
   name.scan(/\w+/) 
end

p titleize("ayan roy") #=>["ayan", "roy"]
```

Now your line `name.scan(/\w+/) { |x| x.capitalize! }` , `x` is passed as `"ayan", "roy"`. Now look at the below:

```
def titleize(name)
   name.scan(/\w+/) { |x| p x.capitalize!  } 
end

p titleize("ayan roy")
```

*Output:*

```
"Ayan"
"Roy"
"ayan roy"
```

As [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) says:

> ***scan(pattern) {|match, ...| block } → str - if block is given,scan will return the `receiver` on which it is called. Both forms iterate through str, matching the pattern (which may be a Regexp or a String). For each match, a result is generated and either added to the result array or passed to the block.***

Comment: does the corrected code at the top treat the input from word as array?

Answer (score 2):

`scan` returns/yields new strings and will never modify the source string.  Perhaps you want `gsub`.

```
def titleize(name)
  name.gsub(/\w+/) {|x| x.capitalize }
end
```

Or perhaps better to use a likely more correct implementation from the  [titleize gem](https://github.com/granth/titleize).

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `#scan` returns new `String` objects which are the results of the Regexp and passes them to the block. So in your method you essentially took these new objects, mutated them by calling `#capitalize!` but never used them anywhere afterwards.

You should do instead:

```
def titleize(name)
  name.scan(/\w+/).each { |x| x.capitalize! }.join(' ')
end
```

But this seems more readable to me:

```
def titleize2(name)
  name.split(' ').each { |w| w.capitalize! }.join(' ')
end
```

Note however these methods do not mutate the original argument passed.

Answer (score 0):

The block form of `scan` returns the original string, regardless of what you do in the block.  (I think you may be able to alter the original string in the block by referring directly to it, but it's not recommended to alter the thing you're iterating over.) Instead, do your `split` variation, but instead of `each`, do `collect` followed by `join`:

```
name.split(" ").collect { |x| x.capitalize }.join(" ")
```

This works for titles containing numerals and punctuation, as well.