# How to replace all capital letters with an empty space in a string

Tags: ruby

I want to replace capitals with spaces. An example string is `"Hey MrsMccarthy"`. I want it to return `" ey rs ccarthy"`.

I tried different ways shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066462/ruby-regex-scan-vs-split-method) to adapt it to my problem, but it doesn't seem to work. I first looked at how to find the capitals, for which I used:

```
string.scan /\p{Upper}/ # => ["H", "M", "M"]
```

but I am not sure how to combine so that it returns:

```
"ey rs ccarthy"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
"Hey MrsMccarthy".tr("A-Z", " ")
# => " ey  rs ccarthy"
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
string = "Hey MrsMccarthy"
string.gsub(/\p{Upper}/, ' ')
#=> " ey  rs ccarthy"
```