# Rails: How to make humanized attributes titlecase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails humanizes attribute names automatically. I would like to make these humanized names title case. For example, `MyModel.full_name` is currently shown as `'Full name'` but I would like the "n" capitalized: `'Full Name'`.

I'm currently defining multi-word attributes in en.yml, which is not DRY at all. I would like to override `.humanize`. What's the best way to make `.humanize` work the way I want?

**Bonus question:**

Unfortunately, Rails' `.titleize` ignores English title rules. Words like 'a' and 'to' should not be capitalized, unless they're first or last word of the string. How can we fix this too?

`MyModel.time_to_failure` should be `'Time to Failure'` but `MyModel.send_to` should be `'Send To'`.

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842444/ruby-on-rails-converting-somewordhere-to-some-word-here

Comment: How about do [`include HumanAttributeOverride`](https://gist.github.com/aruprakshit/113ee1e08d8f6efee2ddbbd2644e0463)  in each model? `HumanAttributeOverride` is a concern module.

Comment: If you have a small enough amount of words that won't be capitalized and you know the set, then do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251311/capitalizing-titles

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions! @Arup Rakshit, your suggestion pointed me to `ActiveModel::Translation#human_attribute_name`, which turned out to be the way to do this in Rails 4.

Here's what I did:

---

**Gemfile**:

```
gem 'titleize'
```

---

**config/initializers/human_attribute_name.rb**:

```
# Overrides human_attribute_name so model attributes are title case.
# Combine with the titleize gem which overrides String#titleize with English-language rules.
module ActiveModel::Translation
  def human_attribute_name(attribute, options = {})
    options   = { count: 1 }.merge!(options)
    parts     = attribute.to_s.split(".")
    attribute = parts.pop
    namespace = parts.join("/") unless parts.empty?
    attributes_scope = "#{self.i18n_scope}.attributes"

    if namespace
      defaults = lookup_ancestors.map do |klass|
        :"#{attributes_scope}.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key}/#{namespace}.#{attribute}"
      end
      defaults << :"#{attributes_scope}.#{namespace}.#{attribute}"
    else
      defaults = lookup_ancestors.map do |klass|
        :"#{attributes_scope}.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key}.#{attribute}"
      end
    end

    defaults << :"attributes.#{attribute}"
    defaults << options.delete(:default) if options[:default]
    defaults << attribute.titleize

    options[:default] = defaults
    I18n.translate(defaults.shift, options)
  end
end

# If you're using Rails enums and the enum_help gem to make them translatable, use this code to default to titleize instead of humanize
module EnumHelp::Helper
  def self.translate_enum_label(klass, attr_name, enum_label)
    ::I18n.t("enums.#{klass.to_s.underscore.gsub('/', '.')}.#{attr_name}.#{enum_label}", default: enum_label.titleize)
  end
end
```

---

If you're not using enums and enum_help, delete the last bit.

A concern would have worked too, but in my project, there was no reason not to apply it to every model.

Beautiful!